# What does $w=-1$ mean for the equation of state of the cosmological constant?

Tags: cosmology, space-expansion, universe, cosmological-constant

The Planck collaboration has measured $w=-1.0$ for the equation of state of the cosmological constant Lambda. Can somebody explain what this means?

(1) Does $w=-1.0$ mean that Lambda was constant over time in the past?

(2) Does $w=-1.0$ mean that Lambda is made of virtual (instead of real) particles?

(3) Does $w=-1.0$ mean that Lambda/dark energy is not made of massive real particles?

Or does $w=-1.0$ mean something else? (What would $w=+1$ mean? What would $w < -1$ mean?)

Answer (score 2):

The density $\rho$ as a function of the scale factor $a$ is proportional to

$$\rho \propto a^{-3(1+w)}$$

so if you set $w=-1$ like we do for the dark energy density you get

$$\rho \propto a^0 = \text{constant}$$

Only if $w=0$ the material can be made of massive particles, since regular material has to thin out the overall density inversely proportional to the growing volume so that $\rho \propto a^{-3}$.

If $w<-1$ you would have the dark energy density increase with the scale factor like it does in the big rip model, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equation_of_state_(cosmology)).